# Why is my game not built?

Tags: unity, build-process

I have a simple Unity game with a single scene, which I am trying to build for Windows:

[image]

When I click "build", I am prompted to select a folder. I choose an empty folder and click "Select Folder". Then I see some pop-up messages as well as this warning:

[image]

But, the folder remains empty - nothing is built there.

How can I debug this error?

EDIT: I tried to build from the command line:

```
Unity -batchmode -projectPath D:\gamedev-code\01-unity-basics -buildWindows64Player D:\GameBuilds\01-basics-windows\
```

I got an error:

```
Aborting batchmode due to failure:
Failed to build player.
```

which is not very helpful..

Comment: Did you happen to select a folder inside your assets directory, causing Unity to think the build being written was a new asset to import?

Comment: @DMGregory No: the folder is `D:\GameBuilds`, that I created specifically for game builds.

Comment: I tried to build a different Unity project into the same folder, and it worked just fine. Is there a way to build a game from the command line, so I can see if there are any error messages?

Comment: Error messages should be printed to the console window and editor log. But if you want to build from the command line, a [quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+build+command-line&ia=web) will lead you to [the command line arguments you need](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditorCommandLineArguments.html) and [tutorials for how to use them](https://fadhilnoer.medium.com/automating-unity-builds-part-1-ba0c60e8d06b).

Comment: If you can build another project, then one way you can narrow down the problem here is to start copying content from the project that won't build into the project that will. Every so often in that process, try to build again. If you hit a point where the build stops working, you know something in the last batch of additions is related to causing the error, and you can look closer at that content to try to distill it down to a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. If you don't hit a spot where the build stops working, then you can set sail in your brand new ship of Theseus project.

Comment: @DMGregory I did this, and indeed I found that there was a compilation error in a script I did not use. I did not notice it before, because the scene runs fine without this script. Probably, when I tried to build, Unity tried to compile all the scripts - even those not in the scene. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Be sure to post that as an Answer below. And remember to keep an eye out for errors in your console dialog. Unity will print an error there on every compilation pass if something fails to compile, so you should get in the habit of fixing those right away even if the script is unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a compilation error in a script I did not use.

I did not notice it before, because the scene runs fine without this script.

I have learned that, when building a game, Unity tries to compile all the scripts - even those not in the scene.

Comment: It has to do that since you can have more than one scene in your build.

Comment: Moreover, it's not always possible to determine whether a script is used or not (this comes down to the Halting Problem - you could have code that fetches a reference to the script by reflection, using a string that's composed at runtime, etc...). So "Compile everything, then strip out the subset of code we can verify is dead" is about the best policy we can use.

Comment: If a script is not referenced at all, I do not see why it should be compiled.